# Compairing multiple distributions from repeated measures design to a refrence value

Tags: r, repeated-measures, independence, z-test

I have 24hrs of temperature measurements taken in one minute intervals for a set of individuals. Thus, there is a non-independent distribution of temperatures for each individual as each measurement is correlated with the previous and subsequent measurement within the individual (repeated measures).

I want to compare the overall distribution of temperatures (at the population level) to a fixed reference value.

A one-way Z-test seems like the most appropriate approach for comparing a distribution to a fixed value, but how can I account for the repeated measures design?

In case it is useful - I am performing the analysis in R.